# Why is my listview not showing populated data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to populate a listview with database values depending on button parameter that has been passed. Here is my scenario.

```
   <Button x:Name="ViewFormOne" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="3" 
           Content="Form 1" Style="{StaticResource KwegaLinkButton}">
           <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">                                                
                   <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ClassDetails}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding Content, ElementName=ViewFormOne}" />                                                                                                
               </i:EventTrigger>
           </i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.LostMouseCapture">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowFormOneData}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
         </Button.Triggers>
   </Button>
```

So when a user clicks button with content form 1 the listview that resides on a different user control should be updated and show this data. Below is code to viewmodel.

```
private ObservableCollection<Student> formOneDetails;
public ObservableCollection<Student> FormOneDetails
   {
      get
        {
            return formOneDetails;
        }
      set
        {
            if (value == formOneDetails)
                 return;
                formOneDetails = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FormOneDetails");
        }
    }

internal ObservableCollection<Student> FetchClassDetails(string detailed_class_name)

   {
     if (!StudentTableDoesntExist)
        {
          formOneDetails = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
          DataTable dtable = _student.GetFormOneStudents(detailed_class_name);

          if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
               {
                  foreach (DataRow row in dtable.Rows)
                      {
                         var values = row.ItemArray;
                         var student = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, email, className, streamName, studentCode, enrollmentNo,
                                phoneNo, emergencyContact, gender, student_nationality, dateOfBirth, dateOfJoin, profilePic, isDiscontinued,
                                isConfirmedByAdmin)
                            {
                                student_id = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]),
                                first_name = values[1].ToString(),
                                last_name = values[2].ToString(),
                                email = values[3].ToString(),
                                class_name = values[4].ToString(),
                                stream_name = values[5].ToString(),
                                student_code = values[6].ToString(),
                                enrollment_no = values[7].ToString(),
                                phone_no = values[8].ToString(),
                                emergency_contact = values[9].ToString(),
                                gender = values[10].ToString(),
                                nationality = values[11].ToString(),
                                date_of_birth = values[12].ToString(),
                                date_of_join = values[13].ToString(),
                                profile_pic = values[14].ToString(),
                                is_discontinued = Convert.ToBoolean(values[15]),
                                is_confirmed_by_admin = Convert.ToBoolean(values[16])
                            };
                            formOneDetails.Add(student);
                            ClassCount = formOneDetails.Count;
                        }
                    }            
                }
                return formOneDetails;
            }

    public ICommand ClassDetails
            {
                get
                {
                    if (classDetails == null)
                    {
                        classDetails = new CommandBase(i => FetchClassDetails(i as string), null);
                    }
                    return classDetails;
                }
            }
```

I pass button name as parameter to ClassDetails command and fetch the details from database. All this works fine but formoneDetails doesn't recieve the returned value from fetchclassdetails method. The databinding and datacontext for the listview on its usercontrol all look fine below is the code.

```
 <ListView x:Name="FormOneView" ItemsSource="{Binding studentViewModel.FormOneDetails, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding studentViewModel.SelectedStudent, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                   
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding parentViewModel.SelectedStudent}">
```

Hope my question is kind of clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting your property. Directly setting your classmember circumvents the setter and therefor the property changed notification.

Your form is never notified.

FetchClassDetails should not modify any class fields at all and use a *local* variable which it returns.

Instead, your command should read:

```
classDetails = new CommandBase(i => FormOneDetails = FetchClassDetails(i as string), null);
```

Comment: @capdiz Did you set breakpoints and debugged? Does it reach your function? Does it reach the setter? Does it call the notification? What is your current code?

Comment: on formonedetails.add(student) i get this error.. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection"

Comment: @capdiz Please add your current code to your post, we cannot help you if we don't know your code.